# How to improve this code in order to be run multithreaded?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gcc, openmp

I've just started using OpenMP directives to use multiple threads. This piece of code however runs fastest using the single threaded version. In my eyes the algorithm should scale nicely since the computations are independent. What's happening here? How can I improve the code?

```
#include <omp.h>

std::vector<Track> interpolateTracks(const std::vector<Track>& tracks,  double segmentLength) {
    typedef std::vector<Track>::const_iterator iterator;
    std::vector<Track> list;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(list, tracks, segmentLength)
    {
        std::vector<Track> local;
        iterator myBegin = threadBegin(tracks.begin(), tracks.end());
        iterator myEnd = threadEnd(tracks.begin(), tracks.end());
        for (iterator i = myBegin; i < myEnd; ++i) {
            const Track& t = *i;
            TrackInterpolator interpol(t);
            const Track& result = interpol.bySegmentLength(segmentLength);
            local.push_back(result);
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            list.insert(list.end(), local.begin(), local.end());
            std::cout << "Done: " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

The functions `beginThread(begin, end)` and `endThread(begin,end)` return small chunks of the range defined by `begin` and `end` according to the current thread number and the number of threads.

Here's their implementation:

```
#include <omp.h>

template <class I>
I threadBegin(I begin, I end) {
    int part = omp_get_thread_num();
    int parts = omp_get_num_threads();
    double chunk = (end - begin)*1.0/parts;
    ptrdiff_t diff = (ptrdiff_t) (chunk*part);
    return begin + diff;
}

template <class I>
I threadEnd(I begin, I end) {
    //the end of i is the begin of i+1
    int part = omp_get_thread_num() + 1;
    int parts = omp_get_num_threads();
    if (part == parts) {
        return end;
    } else {
        double chunk = (end - begin)*1.0/parts;
        ptrdiff_t diff = (ptrdiff_t) (chunk*part);
        return begin + diff;
    }
}
```

I'm running the code on a linux machine with 16 cores.

Unfortunately I only have access to a bit outdated gcc ((SUSE Linux) 4.5.1 20101208), just in case this might be the reason.

P.S. my first version used a parallel for loop with the `list.push_back(..)` in a *critical* section, which was even slower than the variant posted here.

Comment: Hmm, it's a creative way to do OpenMP, but the big question is - what do the 'threadBegin' and 'threadEnd' function look like?

Comment: Which piece of code is the most time-consuming? What is going on inside `interpol.bySegmentLength(segmentLength);`?

Comment: I've just added the implementations. `interpol.bySegmentLength(segmentLength);` and `TrackInterpolator interpol(t);` should be the most time consuming calls.

Comment: @Sebastian: Sorry, I still cannot see the code of `interpol.bySegmentLength(segmentLength);`. :) Also, have you verified that `begin...` and `end...` return disjoint intervals for each thread?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code seems correct, but here are the possible performance problems that I see:

1. The critical section is, of course, a performance killer, especially if the calculations are not too expensive and/or the vector of Tracks is not very large.
2. The fact that you are storing Track objects, means that you have to copy-construct them when you move them from the local vectors to the final one.
3. You know the final size of your vectors, yet you dynamically grow them.
4. the threadBegin and threadEnd functions make use of floating point arithmetic and FP to integer conversion. These, and the conversion especially, are much slower that doing the equivalent integer operations.

Here is what I suggest:

1. Store std::unique_ptr in your vectors.
2. Pre-allocate your vectors to the final size.
3. To avoid needing a critical section at the end, I see two options:
   a) Work directly in the final array, but finding the correct chunk. Since it will pre-allocated, you don't have to protect it.
   b) work in the local vectors, but then do a copy from within the thread to the correct chunk of the preallocated final vector.
4. Calculate your chunks using integer math - you should be able to do most of the calculations before you fork, then just correct the size of the last chunk.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried 2., 3. I will post the code soon. Anyway, it didn't solve the problem, although I managed to completely avoid creating new vectors. I cannot do 1. because it would cause too many changes. 4. is not needed in the new variant. I think the partitioning did not cause the issue anyway.